# error on upgrade to 5.3

Tags: upgrade, payment-processor

upon upgrade from 4.7.31 to 5.3 the site could not load any civi pages, it would give a generic error message.

in the log I see:

Civi\Payment\Exception\PaymentProcessorException: CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalImpl: Payment processor type is not defined! in CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalImpl->__construct() (line 73 of /var/www/xxxxxx/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalImpl.php).

but this site does not use paypal, it uses authorizenet so I have no idea why this is causing a fatal error

my temp workaround was to just comment out line 73 of PayPalImpl.php but I'll need to verify that payments still work. Anyone else have a similar issue with 5.3?

Comment: I've confirmed that authorizenet payments work fine with this line commented out; I'll see if I can dig deeper into this bug later, please post a comment if you've hit this same issue so I know if this is a real bug or just my server

Comment: Please create an issue for this on https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues

Comment: @ericG I would be checking to see what is going on in the `isPayPalType` function as that is returning FALSE which is causing the error to be thrown as per https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/8acddb67077a09d8ca05e0bc367d2e9598cd8c91#diff-96a0ea19e8ac102ef100c35b3b3d1c31

Comment: what rows do you have in civicrm_payment_processor table?

Comment: At a guess, I would say that you have probably got some paypal contributions but don't have a paypal processor configured?

Comment: all rows in the payment_processor_table and payment_processor_table_type are either the default/dummy or authorizenet. 
no payments, to my knowledge, have ever been taken via paypal

Comment: I think this is something specific to this one site, I have upgraded a few other clients today that also do not use paypal and can't replicate this error on those sites

Answer (score 1):

I posted this to gitlab here https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/250 and the issue turned out to be related to odd records in my database.

this query, from Elieen exposed the bad row

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.class_name, p.is_active, pt.id, pt.class_name, pt.name
FROM civicrm_payment_processor p
LEFT JOIN civicrm_payment_processor_type pt ON pt.id = p.payment_processor_type_id
+----+--------------------+----------------------+-----------+------+----------------------+---------+
| id | name               | class_name           | is_active | id   | class_name           | name    |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+-----------+------+----------------------+---------+
|  1 | Dummy Processor    | Payment_PayPalImpl   |         1 |   10 | Payment_Dummy        | Dummy   |
|  2 | Dummy Processor    | Payment_Dummy        |         1 |   10 | Payment_Dummy        | Dummy   |
```

so I updated the row in civicrm_payment_processor to change Payment_PayPalImpl to Payment_Dummy and everything works without the modification to civi code.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same message after updating from 5.2.1 to 5.3.2. I have 2 sites, neither have any contributions configured, either thru paypal or anyone else. Both sites were upgraded. The other is working fine but this one cannot get into civi from drupal entry.

Civi\Payment\Exception\PaymentProcessorException: CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalImpl: Payment processor type is not defined! in CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalImpl->__construct() (line 73 of /mysite/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalImpl.php).

I took the advice of editing out line 73 and all is good.

Comment: @ericg's [solution to correct the entries in DB table `civicrm_payment_processor`](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/26081/149) looks like the right answer, please try that instead?